# Progress bar shound start after open lightbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have a progress bar inside a light box. The problem is that progress bar starts to fill when the page is loaded, and not when I open the the lightbox. Is there a way to fix this? My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/D9NBY/

```
<div class="prog">
<div id="filler" class="filler"></div>
</div>


<script>    
var stepSize = 50;
setTimeout((function() {
var filler = document.getElementById("filler"),
percentage = 0;
return function progress() {
  filler.style.height = percentage + "%";
  percentage +=1;
  if (percentage <= 100) {
    setTimeout(progress, stepSize);
 }
}

}()), stepSize);
</script>
```

Comment: in my jsfiddle you will see that the progress bar starts before I open the lightbox window...

Comment: I don't see where you're using jquery in your code posted here, or in your fiddle...

Comment: any idea how to fix my code in order to make progress bar starts when lightbox opens? can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your progress bar is starting when the document loads because **that's when you are executing the `setTimeout` that starts it**.

You should be able to fix it by wrapping this call inside another function that you execute when you want (when you're making it visible) instead of on load.

Something like this:

```
function start() {
    var stepSize = 50;
    setTimeout(...);
}
```

Then add this to your `onclick` handler in your html:

```
start();
```

[Here is an updated fiddle that demonstrates it working](http://jsfiddle.net/QHMKk/2/).

Comment: looks nice... can you help please and see this in jsfiddle working?

Comment: I have try it but seems I cannot do it.

Comment: cannot find words to thank you... you saved me a lot of time from this morning...thanks